# How does gorm determine which table to use?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I want connect to SQL SERVER using gorm. I've read documentation how to create new record in table. There is a code:

```
user := User{Name: "Jinzhu", Age: 18, Birthday: time.Now()}

db.NewRecord(user) // => returns `true` as primary key is blank

db.Create(&user)

db.NewRecord(user) // => return `false` after `user` created
```

I do not understand, how `gorm` indicate which table is inserting current record? By struct field or what?

Comment: It uses the name of your type. Here the type is `User` so `gorm` will use the `users` table by default. You can also configure it to not use the plural form if you'd like.

Comment: @Ullaakut how to do that?

Comment: http://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Pluralized-Table-Name this should explain you how to use custom table names